# VIM - add a vcs flag for current file

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I want to add a flag next to the filename on the statusline.

e.g:

`filename M`   for modified
`filename A`   for added
`filename ??`  for untracked

Essentially, is there something similar to the flag `%m`? if not, how should I go about this to quickly fetch the vcs status of the current file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`system('git status --porcelain ' . expand('%:p')` on BufEnter and BufWritePost does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Fugitive is a great git plugin in general and provides hooks for you to add status indicators in your statusline.

https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive

Comment: I'm aware of that plugin but it does not have what I want: `Add %{fugitive#statusline()} to 'statusline' to get an indicator with the current branch in (surprise!) your statusline.` It only gives me the branch not the file status